# Compressing to cool and then infinite cooling

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, heat-conduction

*Temperature is directly related to volume, and pressure is inversely related to volume.( It is known)
So if we increase the pressure of a gas then it converts into ice which is cold if we store it in a container with high tensile strength 
Then can we get continuously cold temperature from it? 
Solution for Global warming 
As is cannot covert back into gas due to tensile strength

Comment: It is not clear, at least to me, what you are asking. Your first statement and the link relate to the ideal gas law. Your second statement relates to phase change which has nothing to do with your first statement. The two final "then" statements make no sense to me at all. You need to edit your question so we know what it is, otherwise it will be closed.

Comment: I am very sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: I honestly didn't mean to convey to you an inconvenience. I am only trying to help you get your question answered by being more clear as to what your question is. Otherwise others will vote to close because it is unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is wrong here. When you compress a gas, it does not get cold: instead it heats up. If we then allow that hot parcel of compressed gas to shed its heat to the environment, we can then get that parcel of gas to chill down and get cold by releasing the pressure. This is the basic principle upon which many air conditioning units function.

Note here that the act of compressing the air takes work, which means that the refrigerating effect consumes energy. Note also that the heat released during the compression phase leaves the gas and enters the environment, raising its temperature, and that heat release will inevitably exceed the amount of heat which the refrigeration process will absorb.

This means that running a refrigerator in a closed room with the refrigerator door open will always heat the room up, and not chill it. This in turn means that you cannot combat global warming using refrigerators: instead you make the problem worse by burning fuel to make the electricity to run the refrigerator, whose output is essentially wasted.

Comment: What if we solidify the gas by increasing pressure and decreasing temperature and then store it in a container with high tensile strength and high conductivity

Comment: Same outcome. once the compression heat has conducted itself out of the squished gas, you can then release the pressure and obtain refrigeration as the gas liquifies and then evaporates. But you still must perform the compression work, which consumes energy, and the compression heat still warms up the environment.

Comment: If the container is continuously providing the compression work and can handle the pressure of the gas, so can it be said that it has turned into an infinite source of cold or warm as we aren't releasing the pressure at all just the temperature is allowed to be released then will there be a difference of temperature in the container (sealed)